# Set data to $rootScope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

So far I have used many times $rootScope and I had no bigger problems. Now it is a problem where i need to set $http.get to $rootScope. I always get undefined
Here is ctrl

```
 $http.get(serviceBase + 'aaaa/aaaa/' + $stateParams.klupaID)
            .success(function (data) {
        $rootScope.klupaCreatedAt = data.created_at;
    });
```

Also i try make factory, but i have same problem.

```
$scope.currentKlupa = sveKlupeServiceFactory.get({klupa: $stateParams.klupaID});
    $scope.currentKlupa.$promise.then(function (data) {
        $rootScope.klupaCreatedAt = data.created_at;

    })
```

Can someone help me, how to set on $rootScope my response data. 
I try solution from here [Why I can't set/get $rootScope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35126369/why-i-cant-set-get-rootscope) and from here [Cannot get to $rootScope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10486769/cannot-get-to-rootscope) but without success
Thnx

EDIT:
here is plunker link https://plnkr.co/edit/GOq1MT7eqxBDMtkuYVvr?p=preview

Comment: With the code provided, no real conclusions can be drawn in regards to your problem.  Please provide more of your code.  Maybe the entirety of your factory code and your controller code.

Comment: i edited my question, there is plunker link

Comment: I guess your issue came from your API that returns `undefined`, not from `$rootScope`...

Comment: if i add under $promise, console.log($rootScope.klupaCreatedAt);, i get data normaly

Comment: You want to **show in HTML** `$rootScope.klupaCreatedAt`?

Comment: No, take a look at my plunker. I want to get $rootScope.klupaCreatedAt to minDate for datepicker  on line 76 in my controller. If i set everything inside success, datepicker don't working